# RGB888 to RGB565 issue using Bruno library for Swift In Release mode

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I am trying with Bruno library(pod) in Swift with Xcode 12.4 to convert RGB888 to RGB565. It's working fine in debug mode but in release mode it's always giving me black image.

https://github.com/appunite/bruno-ios

```
guard originalImage != nil, let encodedData = originalImage!.encodeRGB565(width:800 , height: 480) else {
    return nil
}

let decodedImage = encodedData.decodeRGB565(width: 800, height: 480)
```

decodeRGB565 returns as black image in decodedImage parameter. I tried with both .png and .jpeg format.

When I generate a log file (Text File In Document Directory), I observed that 'encodedData' always return values a 0 values in its complete allocated memory.

My guess is the function 'vImageConvert_RGBA8888toRGB565' which library is using is not working as expected in release mode.

Any help will be appreciated